# dh-virtualenv build error - text file busy

Tags: python, debian

Just getting started with dh-virtualenv and have been following the tutorial at https://nylas.com/blog/packaging-deploying-python/

I have a trivial 2 file test app which I am trying to build on a vagrant Debian Jessie VM running on my windows box. When I run dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc,  I get an error at the end  - unable to rename file - text file is busy:

```
root@jessie:/vagrant/updatetest3#
root@jessie:/vagrant/updatetest3#
root@jessie:/vagrant/updatetest3# uname -a
Linux jessie 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.39-1+deb8u1 (2017-02-22) x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@jessie:**/vagrant/updatetest3# sudo dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc**
dpkg-buildpackage: source package updatetest3
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 1.3
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution unstable
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by bill <bill@bill.com>
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
dpkg-source --before-build updatetest3
debian/rules clean
dh clean --with python-virtualenv
dh_testdir
dh_auto_clean
pyversions: missing X(S)-Python-Version in control file, fall back to      debian/pyversions
pyversions: missing debian/pyversions file, fall back to supported versions
running clean
'build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7' does not exist -- can't clean it
'build/bdist.linux-x86_64' does not exist -- can't clean it
'build/scripts-2.7' does not exist -- can't clean it
dh_clean
dpkg-source -b updatetest3
dpkg-source: warning: no source format specified in debian/source/format, see dpkg-source(1)
dpkg-source: info: using source format `1.0'
dpkg-source: warning: source directory 'updatetest3' is not <sourcepackage>-<upstreamversion> 'updatetest3-1.3'
dpkg-source: info: building updatetest3 in updatetest3_1.3.tar.gz
dpkg-source: **error: unable to rename `/vagrant/updatetest3_1.3.tar.gz.new.WqKLSO' (newly created) to `updatetest3_1.3.tar.gz': Text file busy**
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-source -b updatetest3 gave error exit status 26
root@jessie:/vagrant/updatetest3#
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Bill

Answer (score 1):

Never mind.

The issue seems to have been a result of me trying to build in the directory shared with the host OS ( /vagrant). After  I copied to a guest only dir, problem went away.

Bill